# Using one formula for all rows in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a formula on say Column C:

```
=IF(B2<=6,15,IF(AND(B2>6,B2<=13),20,IF(AND(B2>13,B2<=20),25,IF(AND(B2>=21),30))))
```

Is it possible to have Excel dynamically know that I may be on B3 and copy the result into C3?

right now I am coping the formula into each cell of column C so that the results are calculated correctly.

Comment: Somebody needs Lotus Improv.  Ah, if only things had gone differently in the 90's...

Comment: =LOOKUP(B2,{1,7,14,21},{15,20,25,30}) might be a little easier to read...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need the `ANDs`, this would suffice

`=IF(B2<=6,15,IF(B2<=13,20,IF(B2<=20,25,30)))`

...Not sure what the problem is, do you want to copy the formula down the column? If you put that formula in C2 then put the cursor on the bottom right until you see a black "+" - this is the `"fill-handle"`- then you can double click that and formula will be populated as far as you have data in column B (and cell references will adjust as required row by row)....

Comment: I was thinking it was going to be more complicated than that...thanks!